# Как получить выделенное значение из комбобокса с привязкой данных?

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется `DataTable` с данными. Привязываю его к комбобоксу следующим образом:

```
DataTable dataTable = ...;

comboBox1.DisplayMember = "login";
comboBox1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

На этом этапе всё нормально, данные в комбобоксе отображаются.

В другом месте пытаюсь получить значение из комбобокса:

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

Но вместо логина вижу что-то другое.

Как получить нужное значение?

Comment: кажется вам уже показывали, как работать с базой, но вы по неизвестной причине ничему не научились.

Comment: Как я понял, у вас проблема в получении нужного значения из comboBox1. Но зачем вы написали всё остальное? Вывалили на нас ненужную информацию. Кто захочет помочь, должен продраться через код двух методов.

Comment: Я правильно понял суть вашей проблемы? А теперь вы отредактируйте вопрос, указав, что же именно вы получаете из комбобокса (`System.Data.DataRowView` - да?)

Comment: Я против переоткрытия этого вопроса, так как 1) код в вопросе был изменен не автором, внесена весьма существенная правка, изменяющая воппос почти полность. 2) нулевая активность автора в комментариях.

Comment: @ Alexander Petrov Все верно. Пустое значение. Я потом поменял на Combobox.text и все заработало. Ну еще кое что поменял. Не верный textbox выбирал. Соответственно пароль он не мог проверить.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov и @ aepot  спасибо за подсказки. За помощь какой бы она не была. Я получил результат нужный мне, пусть он не такой как вы умеете делать. Он работает. Я изучаю ADO вообще C# 3 месяца. Но я создал вполне работающие базы на хостинге REG.Ru. 8 таблиц и 12 программ для работы и клиентов с этими таблицами и кассиров для работы с этими файлами и таблицами. Подключил 4 региона к этим базам. Пусть это 100-150 строк в день в базе (мелочь для вас) но для меня огромное достижение в моих знаниям. Вы не сердитесь когда неучи не делают как Вы. Я или тот неуч со временем наступит на грабли

Comment: @Alexander Petrov и @ aepot главное для организации этот результат после журналов EXCEL и многопользовательский доступ это фантастика. Спасибо людям которые как вы ругают, но помогают. Я исправлюсь. Но еще не раз сюда обращусь. Надеюсь поможете )))